# How to find value in table with JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have two entities COMMANDE and ARTICLES that between them an association ManytoMany this association create a new table "DETAIL_Commande" who has two columns  id_commande and id_article and I want to find a value in this table with id_commande with JPA

Article code

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TB_ARTICLES")
public class Article implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id_article ;
private String nom_article ;
private String designation ;
private double prix_unitaire ;
private int quantite;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="TB_DETAIL_COMMANDES"
,joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_article"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_commande"))`enter code here`
private List<Commande> commandes ;
```

Commande entity code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TB_COMMANDES")
public class Commande implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id_commande ;

private String date_commande ;
private String date_livraison ;
private String etat ;
private double montant_ht;
private double montant_ttc;
private int quantite;
@ManyToOne()
private Client client ;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="TB_DETAIL_COMMANDES"
,joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_commande"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_article"))
private List<Article> articles ;
```

I try this code but it doesn't code

```
public List<Article> getAllArticlesByCodeCommande(long code_commande) {
    Query query = entity_manager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM TB_DETAIL_COMMANDES c where c.id_commande like:x");
     query.setParameter("x", code_commande);
     List<Article> article = query.getResultList();
     return article;`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your mapping annotations, you don't have one association between Commande and Article but two associations: both are many-to-many.

If you really want just one association you should choose a side of the association to mark it as `mappedBy`. For example let `Article.commandes` unchanged and do next on `Commande`

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="commandes")
private List<Article> articles ;
```

Back to the question, in the method `getAllArticlesByCodeCommande` is mixing (and is wrong!) *native* mapping information inside a *[JPA](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro.htm#BNBPZ) query* which expects [JPQL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage.htm#BNBTG).
I fix the code to show you and example but you must follow the links to understand JPA. Also [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage005.htm) you can see JPQL examples and syntax.

```
public List<Article> getAllArticlesByCodeCommande(long code_commande) {
    Query query = entity_manager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Commande c JOIN c.articles a WHERE c.id_commande = :x");
    query.setParameter("x", code_commande);
    List<Article> article = query.getResultList();
    return article;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your mappings as suggested by @Guillermo. Also, note that you have to use the Entity/Class name in select query and not the table name as such.

**Incorrect JPA Query:**

```
Query query = entity_manager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM TB_DETAIL_COMMANDES c where c.id_commande like:x");
```

**Correct JPA Query** :

```
Query query = entity_manager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Commande c WHERE c.id_commande like :x");
```

There are different methods (["EntityManager"](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) ) like `createNativeQuery()`, `createQuery()`. Have a look at it. you are trying to mingle NativeQuery and JPAQuery.